Approach to compute pairwise correlations in R for 2 different matrices with partially matched features
I would like to ask for a more "complex" case scenario I'm phasing for analysing high-throughput biological data, aiming to estimate some pairwise correlation coefficients. The input data are two numeric matrices, having the same columns. The first matrix, called mat1, has as feature-names phosphoproteomic IDs, like the following: "X1_Protein_1", "X2_Protein_2", "X56_Protein_3", etc. in detail, the first part before the "" separator represents the different phosphositeID, whereas the second part after the "", depicts the proteinID. Hence, the same proteinID might be annotated with different phosphositeIDs, making multiple features.
On the other hand, the second matrix, called mat2, has as features-rownames, proteinIDs, like the following format: "Protein_1", "Protein_2", "Protein_46", etc. Thus, the rownames in mat2 partially match with the second part of the features names in mat1.
Then, I tried with an arbitary-toy example below, to perform a correlation analysis:
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
mat1 <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10, ncol=10)
rownames(mat1) <- c("X1_Protein_1", "X2_Protein_1", "X3_Protein_2", "X4_Protein_3", 
"X5_Protein_3", "X6_Protein_4", "X7_Protein_5", "X8_Protein_6", "X9_Protein_7", "X10_Protein_8")
colnames(mat1) <- paste0("Sample", 1:10)

mat2 <- matrix(rnorm(70), nrow=7, ncol=10)
rownames(mat2) <- c("Protein_1", "Protein_2", "Protein_3", "Protein_4", "Protein_5", 
"Protein_6", "Protein_7")
colnames(mat2) <- paste0("Sample", 1:10)

# Extract the protein IDs from mat1's row names
mat1_df <- as.data.frame(mat1) %>%
  rownames_to_column(var="Phosphosite") %>%
  separate(Phosphosite, into=c("PhosphositeID", "ProteinID"), sep="_", extra = "merge")

# Subset both matrices to common features
common_proteins <- intersect(mat1_df$ProteinID, rownames(mat2))

mat1_subset <- mat1_df %>%
  filter(ProteinID %in% common_proteins)

mat2_subset <- mat2[rownames(mat2) %in% common_proteins, ]

mat1_df_final <- mat1_subset %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(ProteinID, PhosphositeID),
                                    names_to = "Sample", values_to = "phos_value")

mat2_df_final <- mat2_subset %>% as.data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column(var="ProteinID") %>% 
pivot_longer(cols = -c(ProteinID),names_to = "Sample", values_to = "prot_value") 

to_cor <- mat1_df_final %>%
  left_join(mat2_df_final) %>%
  drop_na()

head(to_cor)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  PhosphositeID ProteinID Sample  phos_value prot_value
  <chr>         <chr>     <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>
1 X1            Protein_1 Sample1     -0.560     -0.710
2 X1            Protein_1 Sample2      1.22      -1.67 
3 X1            Protein_1 Sample3     -1.07       0.519
4 X1            Protein_1 Sample4      0.426     -0.947
5 X1            Protein_1 Sample5     -0.695     -0.962
6 X1            Protein_1 Sample6      0.253      1.13 


overall_correlation <- cor(to_cor$phos_value, to_cor$prot_value,
                           use = "pairwise.complete.obs")


My main conserns-questions are the following:

With the above approach, I estimate a "total", overall correlation estimate, which is important; However, I would also like to compute with some approach all the vectorized-pairwise correlation coefficients for each pair that was compared; So that essentially only the PhosphositeIDs (PhosphositeID) that belong to a specific protein(ProteinID) are compared, and not everything with everything; As the ultimate goal, is to just inspect the correlation of the phosphoproteome with the full proteome; and hence, accurately compute the pairwise correlation between each "group"{Phosphosite-protein} of interest;

To also estimate an accompanying p-value, the following function could also be implemented:



overall_correlation <- cor.test(to_cor$phos_value, to_cor$prot_value,
use = "pairwise.complete.obs")

Thank you in advance,
Efstathios

I think you want nest. First, create a function that does what you want:
cor_fun <- function(df) 
  cor.test(df$phos_value, df$prot_value, use="pairwise.complete.obs") |> 
  broom::tidy() |>
  select(estimate, p.value)

Then, apply this function to your nested data frame
nest(to_cor, .by=c(PhosphositeID, ProteinID)) |>
  mutate(corr=map(data, cor_fun)) |>
  unnest(corr)


# A tibble: 9 × 5
  PhosphositeID ProteinID data              estimate p.value
  <chr>         <chr>     <list>               <dbl>   <dbl>
1 X1            Protein_1 <tibble [10 × 3]>    0.163  0.652 
2 X2            Protein_1 <tibble [10 × 3]>    0.472  0.169 
3 X3            Protein_2 <tibble [10 × 3]>    0.228  0.526 
4 X4            Protein_3 <tibble [10 × 3]>    0.585  0.0758
5 X5            Protein_3 <tibble [10 × 3]>    0.316  0.373 
6 X6            Protein_4 <tibble [10 × 3]>    0.165  0.649 
7 X7            Protein_5 <tibble [10 × 3]>    0.363  0.302 
8 X8            Protein_6 <tibble [10 × 3]>    0.499  0.142 
9 X9            Protein_7 <tibble [10 × 3]>    0.140  0.699


Dear Edward, thanks a gazillion for the customized function and very useful reply, to also include the p-values; In the meantime, before checking today your reply, I also managed to make something similar (see additional comment below); My major question now, is if I would like to show the overall correlation coefficient estimate between the total PhosphositeID and its accompanying protein abundances (keeping of course the exact order), i just have to use the correlation function directly? Like in my original thread? To use this for example in depicting the overal trend in a scatterplot?

  group_by(PhosphositeID, ProteinID) %>%
  summarize(correlation = cor(phos_value, prot_value, use="pairwise.complete.obs"), .groups = 'drop')```

Yes, Jason. You can do cor_fun(to_cor) to get the overall correlation.
